# F# record list expressions

Tags: list, f#, expression, record

Hello my question is about list expressions in F#. I try to create a record that will be stored in a list. I want the `Point` record inside the `Square` record to update from 1-9.
To clear out what I mean it's like when you write `let example = [1 .. 1 .. 9]` and get: `val example : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]`. Here I want the `Point` in the `Square` record to change from `pos = {x=1; y=1}` and get all 9 Squares with the Points `x=1; y=1` to `x=9; y=9`.

```
type Point = {x : int; y : int}
type Square = {pos : Point; side : int; X : int}  //A square got a position, a side length and a value

let defaultSquare = { pos = {x=1; y=1}; side = 10; X = 0 }

let spelplan = [{defaultSquare with pos = {x=1; y=1}} .. {defaultSquare with pos = {x=9; y=9}}]
```

I've tried the code above, I've also tried.

```
let spelplan = [{defaultSquare with pos = {x=1; y=1}} .. {defaultSquare with pos = {x=1; y=1}} .. {defaultSquare with pos = {x=9; y=9}}]
```

I then get a error message that it doesn't support the `+` operator.

I've already read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd547125(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is not working as you expect is, that F# does not know how to *enumerate* your `Square`s - you could try to implement `+` and stuff but instead I would just create the positions (using said [list expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233227.aspx)) and then map them into a `Square list`:

```
let fromPos size v x y = 
    { pos = {x=x; y=y}
    ; side = size
    ; X = v 
    }

[for y in 1..9 do for x in 1..9 -> fromPos 10 0 x y]
```

as an alternative you can do

```
[for y in 1..9 do for x in 1..9 -> (x,y)]
|> List.map (fun (x,y) -> fromPos 10 0 x y)
```

as well of course

The only interesting thing here is surley the way I produce the positions - you can generalize it like this:

```
let positions width height =
    [ for y in 1..height do for x in 1..width -> (x,y) ]
```

which will produce a list of `(x,y)`-tuples from `(1,1)` to `(width,height)`

Comment: Thank you very much for a great response! This was exactly what I was wondering and I feel that I understand even more of this wonderful language.